# A pizza dilemma

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

You are a waiter at a restaurant. The restaurant is known for its signature dish: the Donut Pizza. The Donut Pizza is a 5-inch square pizza with a 1-inch square hole in the middle. After several customer requests, your boss has decided to create the Large Donut Pizza: a 7-inch square pizza with a 1-inch square hole in the middle. He has put it on the menu and informed you. You were supposed to inform the chefs, but you forgot to. Someone placed an order for a Large Donut Pizza. When you asked the chefs for a Large Donut Pizza to give to the customer, they gave you a regular one, and you then realize that you forgot to inform the chefs of this new addition. You quickly ask for another Donut Pizza, having decided to cut up one or both Donut Pizzas and rearrange the pieces into a Large Donut Pizza. You plan to cut up the pizzas in the following arrangement:

> [image]

However, right before you start cutting, your boss, thinking that you are just slicing an already-made Large Donut Pizza, reminds you that a big pizza has to have big slices: all slices must be at least eight square inches. How should you cut up the pizzas and save your job?

Pieces can be rotated but not reflected.

Comment: Any considerations about wastage, number of cuts or how complex a cut is (how many straight-line sub-cuts it requires)?

Comment: @smci There can't be any wastage, but there are no restrictions on the other stuff.

Comment: Ok so given no wastage allowed, is there any criterion we are trying to optimize? Maximal slice size (> 8 sq.in.)? Minimum number/ complexity of cuts?

Comment: Every piece must be at least eight square inches.

Comment: I know that, I'm saying some answers interpreted "slices must be at least 8 sq.in." to mean "larger slice sizes considered better". There are multiple solutions, you didn't give any guidance on which criteria (if any) are considered optimal. (Intuitively, I'd go for minimum number and complexity of cuts).

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see where it specifies how many pieces you're supposed to cut. Is it any number so long as you can rearrange the two pizzas to make one big one? The accepted answer seems to indicate that is the case.

Comment: @EngineerToast There is a bound on the areas of the pieces.

Comment: @EngineerToast: each slice must be >= 8 sq.in., and a pizza is 24 squares, so each pizza can only legally be cut into 2 or 3 slices.

Comment: @smci Got it now, thanks. There isn't a target on number of slices but it's bounded by the size of each. Total pieces will be 4, 5, or 6 (two smaller pizzas each cut into 2 or 3 pieces). You're allowed to leave one pizza intact - meaning it counts as only 1 piece - but you can't do that while also keeping the pieces of the other pizza ≥8 in².

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution where every slice is strictly larger than 8 square inches:

> Now, each slice is exactly 12 square inches:
>
>  [image]

---

I found a solution, and after comparing it to @spherical-wug-in-a-vacuum's solution, I found a solution which uses fewer, larger slices, by combining pairs of slices from @spherical's solution:

> [image]

Comment: Great job! I did not know it was possible to do any such dissection using four pieces.

Comment: Is there a way to make all the pieces have area at least 9?

Comment: @mathlander See my edit - I was thinking about the same question

Comment: Solution 1 even works without any rotation.

Comment: Solution 1 gives perfect utilization and converts 2 DPs to 1 LDP. Also only requires two straight cuts (and due to the symmetry, we could perform 2x one long cut across both DPs). Other solutions will require wastage, asymmetric cuts and/or multiple cuts.

Comment: @smci: Your other points are all good, but there’s no need to worry about *wastage* — that’s clearly already ruled out by the original question.  2 DP’s have exactly the same area as 1 LDP (2 x 24 = 48), so there’s no surplus pizza available to waste.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: in general you could make asymmetrical pieces, or different-sized pieces (although in this particular 5x5 case, if we only allow *orthogonal cuts* contiguity seems to force us to only have two possibilities for slicing up a DP. Although there could be other valid solutions using sloped lines. For most arbitrary sloped-line cuts you can think of, there would be wastage.)

Comment: @smci: Asymmetrical, sloped, curved, or even fractal cuts can’t change the total area available!  Short of going full Banach-Tarski and using non-measurable sets, no way of dissecting two area-24 shapes and rearranging into an area-48 shape can have any wastage.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I didn't necessarily say "two pizzas"; we could use 3+ (inefficiently) and have wastage. Anyway, as to pieces with sloped cuts, consider cuts from the top left corner (0,5) to the hole (2,3). (Sure, we could always dissect pieces from two area-24 pizzas with arbitrary further cuts to make them fit the area-48 one.)

Comment: @smci: Certainly, if we started with more pizzas, we could have solutions with wastage — but the original question gives us two pizzas, so I thought we were taking that as fixed.  Regarding those sloped cuts you describe — OK, I’m considering them; now what?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I thought the anecdote involving "you take two pizzas" was just a motivation, not a hard limit. Think of slicing 3 or 4 pizzas. Also, think of legal tilings using that diagonal sloped cut.

Comment: @smci It IS a hard limit, but I was not able to convey that well with the backstory.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Even if we go full Banach-Tarski, I think there is a theorem saying that no dissection and reassembly can change area in 2 dimensions.

Comment: @isaacg: which software did you use to draw that diagram? In particular not just for polyominoes (orthogonal edges), but will also let me draw sloped lines?

Comment: @smci This is Google Sheets, I don't know of a way to use it to draw sloped lines.

Comment: I also used Sheets for my diagram!

Answer (score 12):

This is a solution that I have found:

> [image: a solution]

Comment: Exactly the intended solution! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruvv3.png